# How to Launch a specific screen from native background Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager, dart-pub

So far I had gone through many stack overflow links but nothing worked so far.

I need to show a PickUp screen to the receiver, which should be called from the background whenever a call is performed by the dialler. How can I achieve this WhatsApp like Pickup screen even when the app is not running in the background in Flutter?

Here is my PickUpScreen

```
class PickUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final Call call;

PickUpScreen({this.call});

@override
_PickUpScreenState createState() => _PickUpScreenState();
}

class _PickUpScreenState extends State<PickUpScreen> {
  final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();

  bool isCallMissed = true;

  addToLocalStorage({@required String callStatus}){
    Log log = Log(
      callerName: widget.call.callerName,
      callerPic: widget.call.callerPic,
      receiverName: widget.call.receiverName,
      receiverPic: widget.call.receiverPic,
      timestamp: DateTime.now().toString(),
      callStatus: callStatus,
    );
    LogRepository.addLogs(log);
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    if(isCallMissed){
      addToLocalStorage(callStatus: CALL_STATUS_MISSED);
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Incoming...",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            CachedImage(
              widget.call.callerPic,
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              radius: 180,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.call.callerName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 75,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.call_end),
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    isCallMissed = false;
                    addToLocalStorage(callStatus: CALL_STATUS_RECEIVED);
                    await callMethods.endCall(widget.call);
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.call),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    isCallMissed=false;
                    addToLocalStorage(callStatus: CALL_STATUS_RECEIVED);
                      await Permissions.cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted()
                          ? Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => CallScreen(call: widget.call),
                              ),
                            )
                          : {};
  }
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know how we can make a background process to run at a specified time in a flutter. Can I use the alarm manager plugin for this.